# Rest function fails before the start

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, debugging

Making API Rest testing, sometimes I meet with a situation, when a Rest function fails, but even the first breakpoint in it is not reached. Obviously, some preliminary settings fail. But what exactly?

Here is the header of the function:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/export" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public Object exportConfiguration(@RequestBody ConfigurationExport configurationExport) {
    try {
        // at return here stands the breakpoint that is never reached:
        return configurationExporterProvider.export(configurationExport);
```

The body of request is:

```
{}
```

As a response I am getting:

```
            <td>HTTP ERROR: 415 Unsupported Media Type
                <p>Problem accessing /cc/api/configuration/export
                    <pre id="message">Unsupported Media Type</pre>
```

OK, thought I - something happens when trying to load the body into configurationExport.  But there is no throwing errors in that class constructor:

```
private ConfigurationExport() {
    documentTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    valueSets = new ArrayList<>();
    configuration = new Configuration();
}
```

And setters and getters created by Lombok. And Lombok, surely, does not know anything about any Media Types.

I agree with application returning me the response with an error message. But where does it appear? Where and how should I look for it?

Comment: I assume for the nomenclature, you are using Spring.So I think, in this case, you forgot consumes (ex.  `consumes = "application/json"`) annotation in `RequestMapping`, because your are passing to the REST method `exportConfiguration` data is not already supported.

Comment: And can I set that consumes = "application/json" somehow from the request side? Sorry for possibly foolish question.

Comment: something like this: `@RequestMapping(value = { "/export" }, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", consumes = "application/json")`. But it is only an example, I do not know if you consumes json ;-)

Comment: Yes, it should consume json. But just now I checked - there are other functions that have not that 'consumes' in the Spring header of the function, too, look the same, but don't return that error and reach the breakpoint in the body of the function.

Comment: I think it is not only what consumes the spring rest method, also what accept the lombok query, it is related to accept header in the http method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your method is called, Spring performs several Validations of the request, and the request headers. You can set a breakpoint in the Spring class method `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()` to debug that, if you need.

Comment: And can I turn on some my checking, in order to put there the breakpoint? For I have not the file DispatcherServlet in the project.

Comment: DispatcherServlet is a Spring class, I assumed you used Spring. If you use Spring, you can open the class in your IDE and set a breakpoint. If you use JavaEE, there is no DispatcherServlet, but... some other Servlet.

Comment: Another way you can declare filter, and check request before you Servlet

Comment: Yes, it is Spring. I have found it it is in the Spring-webvmc jar, in springframework.web.servlet package. And what is the method that I must put the breakpoint in?

Comment: That variant works. Please, add into the answer the info on the jar and package and the doDispatch as the start method. Thank you very much.